# how to initialize BufferedImage before Constructor?

Tags: java, swing

Hi i am trying to initialize BufferedImage instance before constructor.
is it possible ??

i don't know how & where ?
i also don't want to initialize it in method or etc.

when i am trying ti initialize it before constructor it shows me an error.

my code :

```
public static class ImagePane extends JPanel
 {
        private BufferedImage bg;
        java.util.List<Path> imageFiles= getFilesFromDirectory(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("D:\\New folder")); 

        bg = ImageIO.read(new File((imageFiles.get(3)).toString()));

        public ImagePane() 
        {
        }

        public void nextImage(int cnt)
        {
        }
 }
```

i have also try to put `bg` initialization code inside a `try-catch`, but it shows an error.
**Is this possible ?**

Comment: Why don't you just put it in constructor? Anyway, try `{bg = ...}`

Comment: What? An object usually gets initialized through invoking some sort of constructor.

Comment: @JoshM - because i want to initialize it once after that i have to load image dynamically from disk, if i initialize it in constructor, it overwrites new image every time.

Comment: @user2659972: A class can't be declared as static, correct it.

Comment: @AnkurLathi - i have defined method of enum type so it need to define only in static portion only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the [initializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) block.

> Normally, you would put code to initialize an instance variable in a
>   constructor. There are two alternatives to using a constructor to
>   initialize instance variables: initializer blocks and final methods.
>
> Initializer blocks for instance variables look just like static
>   initializer blocks, but without the static keyword:

```
{
        bg = ImageIO.read(new File((imageFiles.get(3)).toString()));
}
```

The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor. Therefore, this approach can be used to share a block of code between multiple constructors.

Comment: suppose i will create object of ImagePane class then will it call constructor and again initialize it or nor ? because i don't want to initialize it everytime only once i want.

Comment: I think someone posted a static version of this earlier, but took it down.  I don't have my Java IDE at work, so I can't test this, but try adding a static in front of the initializer block, and see if that works.

Comment: @user2659972 If you just want it to be initialized it once then you may put an additional static flag. Set the flag to true when it is initialized for the first time, and later simply check if the flag is set.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using the **[initializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) block**.

**Initializer block** is used to initialize the instance data member. It run each time when object of the class is created.

```
public class ImagePane extends JPanel
 {

     private BufferedImage bg;
     private java.util.List<Path> imageFiles;

      {
            imageFiles= getFilesFromDirectory(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("D:\\New folder")); 

            bg = ImageIO.read(new File((imageFiles.get(3)).toString()));
       }

        public ImagePane() 
        {
        }

        public void nextImage(int cnt)
        {
        }
```

Comment: Where has this been all my life?

Answer (score 0):

Loading an image that way requires that you use a try/catch block; try using that in your initialization.

```
try{
    bg = ImageIO.read(new File((imageFiles.get(3)).toString()));
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Could not load image file!");
}
```

Comment: I just noticed you mentioned that this shows an error; can you specify the error?

Comment: i have also use this one but it doesn't work in declaration part.

Answer (score 0):

You know, I ran into this problem earlier while making a game.  I ended up making a static "ImageManager" class which discovered all images on load.  To get the image, I just make a call to the static getImage() method.

ImageManager:   https://github.com/zalpha314/The-Wheel-of-Time/blob/master/src/engine/content/ImageManager.java

I can then get the image using this:
https://github.com/zalpha314/The-Wheel-of-Time/blob/master/src/engine/models/Piece.java#L14